# Pouchdb promise or not a promise return formatting

Tags: javascript, promise, pouchdb

I have situation where I am reading a database to find out if I need to images from the images database to send to the server.  In the following code, I am reading the DB_WorkIssues database and checking each record to see if there is a field called IsAttachmentInserted.  If so, I take values (which are the names of the images to get from the images database) and send them to the server.

I am having a problem figuring out how to set this up.

If there are no records with the IsAttachmentInserted field, then I would do nothing.  So I would assume that I would return a null.  If there is an IsAttachmentInsert value, then I would return a promise that is the .get of the images database and returns a document which is the array of images.

When I am done I do a submit.

I am not sure how to handle the .then after the images promise or null return.

```
function GetDirtyRecords() {
   var startRows
   var iTemp;
   var insertedImages = "";

   DB_WorkIssues.allDocs({ include_docs: true, descending: false }.then(function(response) {
      data = response.rows;
      startRows = data.length;

      iTemp = 0
      for (var i = 0; i < response.total_rows; i++) {
     if (data[iTemp].doc.IsDeleted){
        if(data[iTemp].doc.IsAttachmentInserted)
        {
           if(insertedImages == "")
          insertedImages += ",";

           insertedImages += data[iTemp].doc.IsAttachmentInserted;
        }
        iTemp++;
     }
      }
      if(insertedImages != "")
      {
          return DB_TaskImages.get(id, {attachments: true});
      }
      else
      {
          return ;
      }
      )}.then(function(doc){

         // do something with the attachments

         $("form").submit();
      })
   }
```

I just need to find out how to handle the last part.

Thanks

Comment: `)}.then` has mismatched parenthesis

Comment: You should *always* return a promise. You can resolve that promise with `null` or an empty array or whatever fits to the expected result type.

Comment: You're right, I had to tear the procedure apart to see it.  That's what I was trying to do.  Either pass the promise which returned a document or null.  Then I do a test on the doc to see if what doc was null or some value.  It turns out that if an id doesn't exist it takes jumps to the catch with an error of 404.  That threw me off for a while but since the promise only passes a value (doc) or goes to the catch, testing a null works pretty well.  How else would I pass a null promise?

Comment: `return Promise.resolve(null)`

Comment: Why is it better to pass the promise that the null, would doc not be null in both cases?  Also, I noticed that I cannot access insertedImages  after the .then?  I thought that you could access local variables outside of the promise chain?

Comment: You should always return a promise (for some value, either a document or null or …) so that `GetDirtyRecords().then(…)` never fails - do the handling inside the `then` callback.

Comment: `insertedImages` is a local variable inside the function scope of `GetDirtyRecords`. You might want to [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if you have any problems with that, including the code that tries to access it.

Comment: OK, I will. Thanks.